# How to Create Category in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am new in Xamrin & trying to create a category for UItextField as below

```
using UIKit;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using CoreGraphics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Foundation;

namespace WeatherApp.iOS.Extension
{
    [Category(typeof(UITextField))]
    public static class UITextFieldExtensionMethod
    {
        [Export ("setBottomBorder")]
        static UITextField setBottomBorder(this UITextField self)
        {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<UITextField>() != null);
            self.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
            self.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
            self.Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.FromRGB(red: (System.nfloat)230.0, green: (System.nfloat)230.0, blue: (System.nfloat)230.0).CGColor;
            self.Layer.ShadowOffset = new CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.9);
            self.Layer.ShadowOpacity = 1.0f;
            self.Layer.ShadowRadius = 0.0f;
            return self;
        }
    }
}
```

but getting an error on **[Category(typeof(UITextField))]** as

*cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'string' (CS1503)*

Please suggest me what am I doing wrong while creating a category. I am working with Visual Studio for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Remove:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```

and add:

```
using ObjCRuntime;
```

You added the wrong using.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are `using System.ComponentModel;`, please refer to this api: [CategoryAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). This attribute can only accept a string parameter.

Did you want to use [ObjCRuntime.CategoryAttribute Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/ObjCRuntime.CategoryAttribute/)? With this namespace you can use it successfully.